# can someone help me in laravel to fix when i add image on db i got this D:\youssfi\wamp\tmp\php5571.tmp but i want the original name of image

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

this is my function store in controller :

```
public function store(VehiculeRequest $request)
{
    $image = $request->image_VH;

    if($image->isValid()) {
        $chemin = config('images.path');
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        do {
            $nom = str_random(10) . '.' . $extension;
        } while(file_exists($chemin . '/' . $nom));

        $image->move($chemin, $nom);
    }

    $inputs = array_merge($request->all($image));
    $this->VHRepository->store($inputs);
    return redirect(route('vehicules.index'));
}
```

and this my class repository:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Repositories;

    use App\Vehicule;
    use App\Http\Requests\VehiculeRequest;

    class VHRepository
    {

        protected $Vehicule;

        public function __construct(Vehicule $Vehicule)
        {
            $this->Vehicule = $Vehicule;
        }

        public function getPaginate($n)
        {
            return $this->Vehicule->with('user')
            ->orderBy('vehicules.created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($n);
        }

        public function store($inputs)
        {
            $this->Vehicule->create($inputs);
        }

        public function destroy($id_vehicules)
        {
            $this->Vehicule->findOrFail($id_vehicules)->delete();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the original name, you can use this method `getClientOriginalName`.

So the method in your controller should be like the written below:

**Controller**

```
public function store(VehiculeRequest $request)
{

    $image = $request->image_VH;

    if($image->isValid()) {
        $chemin = config('images.path');
        do {
          $nom = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        } while(file_exists($chemin . '/' . $nom));

        $image->move($chemin, $nom);
    }

    // because the $image variable contain uploadedFile object, you cannot use array_merge on it.
    // if you want to save the original name in your database you have to change the $image variable with $nom
    // and for the usage of array_merge you have to add the second parameter on it
    $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['image_VH' => $nom]);

    // and if you want to use the path also when save that image in your DB
    $inputs = array_merge($request->all(), ['image_VH' => $chemin . '/' . $nom]);

    // and for the last store it
    $this->VHRepository->store($inputs);
    return redirect(route('vehicules.index'));
}
```

You can check this [UploadFile API Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) for more information about what method you can use and also for `array_merge` you can read this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: thanks linktoahref for your help but i have seem problem